# Injecting JPA EntityManager using Spring vs Java EE 6

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, spring-mvc

I'm new to Java EE 6, and even newer to Spring. I'm trying to inject an EclipseLink JPA EntityManager, and am exploring different ways of achieving this. I'm using Glassfish and Derby. In the examples below I'm trying to inject the EntityManager directly into a servlet or controller for simplicity, in practice I will have a DAO class that wraps the EntityManager.

In Java EE 6, I can define a servlet as follows:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns="/app/*")
public class FrontController extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;
}
```

The EntityManager is correctly injected with no further configuration.

Now I want to use Spring, ideally through annotations. Currently, I can define a Controller as follows:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/testurl.htm")
public class ExampleController {
    private EntityManager em;

    @PersistenceContext
    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager em) {
        this.em = em;
    }
}
```

In order for Spring to wire things up correctly, I need to include the following directive in my application context xml file:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="myPU"/>
</bean>
```

If I don't include the snippet above, I get an exception on deploy:
`org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined: expected single bean but found 0`

Having read [this](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/orm.html#orm-jpa-straight) I was under the impression I wouldn't need the above XML snippet. Could anyone confirm if the above snippet will always be required?

Is there another approach - if an EntityManager is successfully injected to my FrontController servlet by the Java EE container, how can this same EntityManager be injected into my Spring application context and made available to other spring beans?

Comment: inject your em into service layer, not your controllers

Answer (score 0):

inject your em into service layer, not your controllers.

A brief snippet (using hibernate4) :

```
@Controller
public class AdminController {

    @Resource(name = "companyService")
    private CompanyService companyService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/AllCompanies", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getCompanies(final Model model) {
    final List<Company> companies = companyService.getAllCompanies();
    //dostuff
    }
```

and service :

```
@Service("companyService")
@Transactional
public class CompanyService {

    @Resource(name = "sessionFactory")
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<Company> getAllCompanies() {
    final Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
//... do stuff
}
```

and relevant bit of app context

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
        p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" p:configLocation="WEB-INF/classes/hibernate.cfg.xml"
        p:packagesToScan="com.mypackage" />

    <!-- Declare a datasource that has pooling capabilities -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
        ... />

    <!-- Declare a transaction manager -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager" 
                p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory" />
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I'm after (as I said, I aim to use a DAO once injection works). In the [link](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/orm.html#orm-jpa-straight) I posted, their `ProductDaoImpl` is free of any Spring dependencies. Their app context xml is also free of any entity manager declaration, suggesting that the default (JEE-container supplied?) entity manager factory is used.

Comment: @zorgbargle a dao is different to a service class/layer, you inject the dao into the service layer, which you inject into the controller. That is spring 2.5 btw, its up to 3.1 now.

Comment: thanks, I realise they are different, but I don't think it changes what I'm trying to do here which is get the underlying injection mechanism working. If I introduce a service layer, I'll just get the same exception when Spring tries to construct the service layer. edit: sorry - only saw your second response now - I'm not sure how AOP changes what I should/shouldn't do [spring-noob!]

Comment: you need the xml snippet, the link does not contradict this. Without the xml snippet no entitymanagerfactory bean is defined.

Comment: The spring [reference for 3.1](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.RELEASE/reference/html/orm.html#orm-jpa-straight) still doesn't mention defining the entitymanagerfactory bean in XML - I thought the point of what they were describing was that you would get a reference to the plain JPA entitymanager injected by the JEE container, rather than the spring-provided instance (which does some additional fancy automatic transaction magic).

Comment: @zorgbargle yes I agree it does look like that. I don't really understand, I have never done it that way. Good luck. Hang on, its not simply that you have the annotation wrong is it ? PersistenceUnit not PersistenceContext ?

Comment: My understanding was that PersistenceContext injected an EntityManager, whereas PersistenceUnit injected an EntityManagerFactory.

Comment: The docs show an example of injecting a factory, and getting an em from that factory, which is different to your code. An em is not thread safe, whereas emf is.